# Datatable changes not reflecting in dataset

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I encountered a problem where datatable changes is not updating in dataset..
I have tried with dataset.acceptchanges()..But not working..
Is there any alternative to this.Since it is long code iam not able to post here..
Myquestion is how can i reflect datatable changes to dataset.

Comment: What kind of changes you updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataSet.AcceptChanges Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx)

From MSDN:

> AcceptChanges and RejectChanges **only apply to DataRow related changes**
>   (that is, Add, Remove, Delete, and Modify). They are not applicable to
>   schema or structural changes.
>
> Calling AcceptChanges **will not replicate these changes back to the
>   data source if the DataSet was filled using a DataAdapter**. In that
>   situation, call Update instead. See Updating Data Sources with
>   DataAdapters for more information.

Choose which option related to your situation.